# Effect on decimal values rounded to the nearest binary representable power of ten precision?

Tags: decimal-expansion

Actually i have some property in my chart control which create auto scale and enable setting that decimal values should be rounded to the nearest binary representable power of ten precision.

If i have following values then what will be effect on the values if they are as:

```
326317120.7       
336446588.6     
328645939.5    
328064491.6     
323417873.9
```

Or

```
.44   
.43      
.23   
.54
```

etc.

What is following line means regarding values conversion:

> *"decimal values should be rounded to the nearest binary representable power of ten precision"*

and how is it effect the values if we apply on some values??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The phrase you have put in quotes does not follow the rules of English sentence construction, so its interpretation is highly unclear. Are you able to plug some values into your "chart control" (whatever that is) and see what comes out? Maybe if we saw the effect on some values we could reverse engineer the thing and figure out what that quotation means.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i  have updated question..

Comment: Are **you** able to plug some values into **your** chart control to see what comes out? I don't think you understood my comment at all.

Comment: Thanks for you comment..I have checked that but not able to figure out that what is changing.. just small example of conversion i need at this time so that i can understand that what it will do...

Comment: "I have checked that" - does that mean you have plugged some values in and you have seen what comes out? Maybe if you share those input-output pairs with us we'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I want to know that if i have value 10.25, then how can we round it to the nearest binary representable power of ten precision. actually i did not understand the meaning of this specified line clearly so i am asking the experts like you.. the resultant rounded value of 10.25 will be solve the problem..

Comment: And as I said from the start, I don't understand the meaning of that line either, since I am not familiar with the dialect of Broken English in which it is written. This doesn't require an expert in Mathematics; more like an expert in Comparative Linguistics.

Comment: Check [this](http://helpdotnetvision.nevron.com/Nevron.Chart~Nevron.Chart.NNumericScaleConfigurator~EnableDecimalRounding.html) link..

Comment: OK, I checked it, and it doesn't help me at all. Write to the people at Nevron. Or maybe see if they know what it means on a computing website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, Put this comment in answer. it will do as you say..  well thanks again for your time.